# DRY Solution For aws_iam_policy_document On Count Enabled Resources

Tags: terraform

## Original Attempt

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lambda_read_secrets" {
    statement {
      actions = [
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
        "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
        "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds"
      ]

      effect = "Allow"
      resources = [
        "${var.enable_test_users == true ? aws_secretsmanager_secret.test_user[0].arn : ""}",
        "${var.enable_prod_users == true ? aws_secretsmanager_secret.prod_user[0].arn : ""}"
      ]
    }

    statement {
      effect    = "Allow"
      actions   = ["secretsmanager:ListSecrets"]
      resources = ["*"]
    }
  }
```

The issue is that this runs into

```
Error: error creating IAM policy test-lambda-logging20211011172058509500000003: MalformedPolicyDocument: Resource  must be in ARN format or "*".
        status code: 400, request id: c5c62446-eba7-450d-b97d-505be530ba2d

  on ../../../../module/lambda/iam.tf line 58, in resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_read_secrets":
  58: resource "aws_iam_policy" "lambda_read_secrets" {
```

because of the empty string.

## Current Solution

Create a `data "aws_iam_policy_document" "dev_lambda_read_secrets"` and `data "aws_iam_policy_document" "prod-lambda_read_secrets"` and do if statements on which environment we're deploying to.

My primary issue with this solution is that it requires me to essentially double declare the same policy with a tweaked set of resources. I would love to just be able to have a single policy declaration with only the resources changing.

Answer (score 1):

Terraform has the [compact](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/compact.html) function. This lets us declare

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "lambda_read_secrets" {
    statement {
      actions = [
        "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue",
        "secretsmanager:DescribeSecret",
        "secretsmanager:ListSecretVersionIds"
      ]

      effect = "Allow"
      resources = compact([
        "${var.enable_test_users == true ? aws_secretsmanager_secret.test_user[0].arn : ""}",
        "${var.enable_prod_users == true ? aws_secretsmanager_secret.prod_user[0].arn : ""}"
      ])
    }

    statement {
      effect    = "Allow"
      actions   = ["secretsmanager:ListSecrets"]
      resources = ["*"]
    }
  }
```